# Idiomatic `is not` in Dart

Tags: dart

Is there a more idiomaic way to express "**is not**" than `!(o is T)`?

```dart
/// Object (o) is not type (T)
/// 
/// Syntax that works but is not concise: `!(o is T)`

final word = 'drow';

if (!(word is String)) print('undoable');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `o is! T`:

```
if (word is! String) print('undoable');
```

See [Type test operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators).